# Querying on Date properties with Endeca

Tags: atg, endeca

Please help me in my problem with implementing Endeca Guided Search 6.3.1 with ATG 10.2

**Background** :
I am implementing basic text search where a user can search for a date (e.g. "24-Feb-2014"), I need to return records which have any date property matching this date.

The data is invoicing data, so there are properties like, paymentDueDate, creationDate etc, that are of type *date*

**Issue** :
The data indexed in Endeca for date type properties is in the form of milliseconds. So when I have to search against a date input, I first parse the string date(*search term*) entered by the user to a millisecond and then fire the query like..

```
URLEneQuery --> N=0&Ntk=All&Ntt=<dateInMillis>
```

My problem is I am not able to search for a whole day when I do this, as the date is converted to a specific millisecond and the records that match will be those which have the exact millisecond as the value for the date properties. I could have tried a range filter on the milliseconds for the start and end of the day, apparently that doesn't work when you are querying "All" instead of a specific property.

**Question** :
Is it possible to index the date properties in Endeca in some date like format, because I don't care about storing/indexing the milliseconds/minutes/hours. I just need the date, so I could fire the query without parsing the string and fire the query on the input date "24-Feb-2014" as it is?

Or if there is another way I could query MDEX using the presentation API?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In Chapter 11 of the [MDEX Developer Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35825_02/MDEX.630/pdf/BasicDevGuide.pdf) there is an example of how you can deal with DateTime properties. The fact that you already have your dates in milliseconds is in line with how it eventually gets ingested by Endeca.

As far as querying the data is concerned, you have two options, you can either build a Range query to get the day back by converting 00:00:01 of the day to milliseconds as the start time and 23:59:59 of the day to as the end value (obviously need to take care of the fault levels of invoices being generated outside the 'missing' 2000 milliseconds but that is for you to figure out). Alternatively you can 'truncate' your DateTime during the data processing phase. What this means is that you need to remove the time portion from the date while you extract it. To achieve this with your outputconfig.xml file, you create a read-only property in your Repository and then populate its value with a new `RepositoryPropertyDescriptor` that strips the time portion.